# Best way to optimize @media queries

Tags: css

I have been working on making my website mobile responsive with media queries. But it's very tiring to have to adjust every element when the width reduces by 50px. I have too many media queries and wish to shorten my code. what is the best way to use media queries? or is there a better alternative to build my responsive design with?

Comment: Sounds like you might benefit from adjusting more elements than strictly necessary at a given breakpoint, in order to have fewer of them.

Comment: Are you using a lot of px units to size things rather than relative units - in particular vw/vh/vmin which will adjust automatically as the viewport dimensions change. Get rid of px units wherever sensible and have a design which changes only at a (very) few breakpoints - big desktop/tablet/narrow phone for example are often adequate.

Comment: I hardly ever use media queries on responsive pages, maybe show some code ([reprex]) so we can point you in the right direction? Here's [some example](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/gOvWZwq) I posted this week, no MQs used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to reponsive, is to use the property, attribute, units ... relative.

you can use box-sizing: border to avoid recaculating the width, height of content. You can use rem, percentage to change size of elements when you code @media screen.

Making the elements depend on each other and depends only on a few initial elements like font-size of html...will be increase responsiveness

you can follow some tutorial about Responsive Beginner JS Project

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FazgJVnrVuI&ab_channel=BrianDesign

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-2Pj5hxwrw&ab_channel=BrianDesign

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS variables. Then within `@media` change the variables as follows.

```
:root{
    --font: 12px; 
}
.title{
    font-size: calc(var(--font) + 10px); 
}
.subtitle{
    font-size: calc(var(--font) + 5px); 
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    :root{
        --font: 15px; 
    }
}
```

There is a w3schools documentation at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp